# Zero-based numbering vs. one-based numbering for sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

What are the advantages of using one over the other? I mean this in the context of sequences and series. For example, should we let the geometric sequence start from $n=0$ or $n=1$ to get $a_n = a_0r^n$ or $a_n = a_1r^{n-1}$, respectively? Another example is the arithmetic sequence, which changes from $a_0 + dn$ to $a_1 + d(n-1)$ based on which number we start with (0 or 1).

Comment: The only advantage of the former, as far as I know, is shorter expressions

Comment: In Taylor series $\sum_0^\infty b_n(x-a)^n$ is the natural way to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes one convention is simpler and more natural, and sometimes the other. It is probably best to stick with the convention that you are presented with, if that is a normal one, unless there is a good reason to alter it. It is a good idea not to chop and change from one to the other in a similar context (e.g. arithmetic or geometric sequences): otherwise you may end up forgetting which convention was assumed by the formula that you remember.

**Edit:** See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1203036/why-arent-mathematical-series-zero-indexed/1203158#1203158) to a related question for specific examples.

Answer (score 0):

Most computer scientists might argue that [numbering should start at zero](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html).

Comment: A computer scientist told me long ago: “Computers count from zero; *people* count from one.”

Comment: In most programming languages designed for mathematics, indexing begins at 1.  Matlab, R, Mathematica, and Fortran are all good examples.